# pivot table in R

Tags: r, pivot, reshape2

I have date dataframe which like that

```
id     weight  beginning_date   end_date     age  categ_car

22     2       1960-06-02       1960-06-02   17     A

17     4       2001-07-02                    19     B
```

I want the following dataframe

```
id     weight  beginning_date   end_date     age  categ_car

22     2       1960-06-02       1960-06-02   17     A
22     2       1961-06-02       1961-06-02   18     A
17     4       2001-07-02                    19     B
17     4       2002-07-02                    20     B
17     4       2003-07-02                    21     B
17     4       2004-07-02                    22     B
```

I know that I can use the melt function from the package reshape 2 to create the pivot but I don't how I can increment date and age?

thank you,

N

Comment: Why `weight` is 1 in first two rows? It should be 2 based on next 4 rows.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I will modify

Answer (score 0):

Here is some help to get you going. You need to get the year from date columns, apply the same function for date columns, and bind them all after:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
AddWeightage<-function(a,x){
  x<-cumsum(rep(1,x-1))
  return(x+a)
}
cols<-c("age")
df[,lapply(.SD,AddWeightage,x=weight), by=.(categ_car),.SDcols=cols]
```

Here is the function to generate date columns:

```
AddWeightDate<-function(a,x){
  x<-cumsum(rep(1,x-1))
  a1<-x+year(a)
  b<-substr(as.character(a),5,10)
  return(sprintf('%s%s',a1,b))
}

cols<-c('beginning_date',"end_date")
df3<-df[,lapply(.SD,AddWeightDate,x=weight), by=.(categ_car),.SDcols=cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete` and `fill` from `tidyr` package to find a solution. Important point is to generate a sequence of dates (increment by 1 year) using `%m+%` operator from `lubridate` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(beginning_date = ymd(beginning_date), end_date = ymd(end_date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(beginning_date = seq(beginning_date, beginning_date %m+% years(weight-1), 
             by="1 year")) %>%
  fill(weight, end_date, age, categ_car) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id)) %>%
  select(id, weight, beginning_date, end_date, age, categ_car)

# # A tibble: 6 x 6
# # Groups: id [2]
#      id  weight beginning_date end_date   age  categ_car
#    <int>  <int> <date>         <date>     <int> <chr>    
# 1    22      2 1960-06-02     1960-06-02    17   A        
# 2    22      2 1961-06-02     1960-06-02    17   A        
# 3    17      4 2001-07-02     NA            19   B        
# 4    17      4 2002-07-02     NA            19   B        
# 5    17      4 2003-07-02     NA            19   B        
# 6    17      4 2004-07-02     NA            19   B
```

**Update:** Based on feedback from OP to handler multiple `begining_date` for same 'id`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(beginning_date = ymd(beginning_date), end_date = ymd(end_date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(beginning_date = seq(as.Date(min(beginning_date), origin="1970-01-01"), 
                  as.Date(min(beginning_date), origin="1970-01-01") %m+% years(weight-1),
                                by="1 year")) %>%
  fill(weight, end_date, age, categ_car) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id)) %>%
  select(id, weight, beginning_date, end_date, age, categ_car)
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
      "id     weight  beginning_date   end_date     age  categ_car
       22     2       1960-06-02       1960-06-02   17     A
       17     4       2001-07-02         NA         19     B", 
       header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note: `NA` has been used instead of `blank` value for `end_date`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have the following error 'from' must be of length 1 ' I don't know what I can do to use seq

Comment: @Nai Did you try on `df` in my answer? If Not pls try on that 1st. My guess is that you got multiple `beginning_date` for same `id` in your data.

Comment: Yes I tried, and it's ok, but when I tried on my df it's not ok, maybe it's because of the type of benning_date, I have a date maybe I need character?

Comment: @Naï `Date` format should work as `lubridate::ymd` returns as `Date`. You can try to convert it to `character` and then use `lubridate::ymd` to convert to `Date`. Is there any `NA` in `begining_date`?

Comment: No I don't have NA in begining_date

Comment: @Naï Its worth trying use of `min` over `begining_date`. Try to change `seq(...` part as `seq(Date(min(beginning_date), origin="1970-01-01"), Date(min(beginning_date), origin="1970-01-01")  %m+% years(weight-1)`

Comment: I don't know the function Date, is not is.Date?

Comment: @Naï I meant `as.Date`

Comment: @Naï I have updated my answer with proper code to handle multiple `begining_date`.